# Throttle amount of log alerts per cycle

Tags: monit

I'm using Monit to send alerts when keywords appear in my maillog :

```
check file maillog with path /var/log/maillog
    if match "ratelimit" then alert
```

Problem is that the keyword can sometimes appear multiple times in a single cycle, which then triggers multiple emails for the same incident.

Is there a way of limiting Monit to a single alert per cycle?

Answer (score 0):

This was fixed in Monit 5.4:

> Monit 5.4 or newer sends only one alert in the given cycle, changelog
>   excerpt:
>
> --8<--
>   * The content match test now sends one event per cycle and pattern.   Even if there are multiple lines matching the same pattern, only   one
>   event will be generated. Also the event rate is fixed now, so   it is
>   possible to require match for X cycles before generating the   event.
>   --8<--

Systems with older packages might find an updated version in a third-party repo.  e.g.:

http://apt.sw.be/redhat/el5/en/i386/dag/RPMS/monit-5.5-1.el5.rf.i386.rpm